# How to convert a scipy LinearOperator into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to convert a **LazyTensor** object, generated using the **Keops** library, into a **Numpy** array. The **LazyTensor** object has no attribute to convert it directly into a **Numpy** array. So, I used the function `aslinearoperator` as a trick function to convert this symbolic tensor object into a scipy linear operator.

```
>>> A shape  (15230, 10) A  KeOps LazyTensor
>>> from scipy.sparse.linalg import aslinearoperator
>>> L = aslinearoperator(A)
>>> L 
>>> <15230x10 _CustomLinearOperator with dtype=float32>
```

My question is how to convert an n-by-m **LinearOperator** to a **Numpy array**?

Comment: Review, for us, what the `LinearOperator` does. Isn't it just an abstract class that implements a matrix-vector multiplication? Basically input the iterative solvers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `A` attribute of the [`MatrixLinearOperator`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py#L773-L826) that is returned to you from [`aslinearoperator`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py#L773) if that works for your instantiation of `L`

```
>>> from scipy.sparse.linalg import aslinearoperator
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> L = aslinearoperator(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
>>> L.A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Otherwise just multiply by the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) (`eye` / `identity` are mostly the same - I just dont know what an *eye* is but do know about the *identity* ;) ) if some other subclass of linear operator is returned (I am unfamiliar with Keops & its objects).

```
L * np.identity(L.shape[1])
```

as the identity will be `(m, m)` and the product will return you the original matrix.

Comment: Thank you @modesitt. The linear object L is a _CustomLinearOperator, it has no attribute 'MatrixLinearOperator'. Multiplying L with an m-by-m identity matrix works.

Comment: IMP NOTE. here the * operator is not an element-wise operation, but instead means matrix multiplication operation.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. `.dot` an identity matrix, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.dot.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.dot

Comment: Thank you @ev-br. Actually three options work, `L = L * np.identity(L.shape[1], dtype=np.float32)`, `L = L.dot(np.identity(L.shape[1], dtype=np.float32))`, and `L = L.matmat(np.identity(L.shape[1], dtype=np.float32))`